Migrating Xamarin Forms into Maui, it is working in Debug Mode but not in Release Mode?
I am migrating xamarin forms into Maui App and I am using visual studio Mac, I am able to running the app in debug mode without any issues but I am unable to run the app in Release mode.
I am using Prism MVVM, and I created CreateWindow in MauiProgram.cs file
 .CreateWindow(async (container, navigation) =>
 {
     try
     {
         if (VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchEver && !AppConstants.IsLoggedInUser && !Convert.ToBoolean(await SecureStorage.GetAsync(AppConstants.ShowBiometricConsent).ConfigureAwait(false)))
         {
             AppConstants.IsLoggedInUser = true;
             SecureStorage.RemoveAll();
             await SecureStorage.SetAsync(AppConstants.LoggedIn, AppConstants.False);
             await SecureStorage.SetAsync(AppConstants.LoggedOut, AppConstants.True);
             await SecureStorage.SetAsync(AppConstants.ShowBiometricConsent, AppConstants.True);
             await SecureStorage.SetAsync(AppConstants.ShowNotificationOptions, AppConstants.True);

             await Theme.SetTheme();

             await ClearLoginCredentials();

             await navigation.NavigateAsync(AppConstants.LoginPage);
         }
         else
         {
             await Theme.SetTheme().ConfigureAwait(false);

             var isLoggedOut = Convert.ToBoolean(await SecureStorage.GetAsync(AppConstants.LoggedOut).ConfigureAwait(false));

             if (isLoggedOut)
             {
                 await ClearLoginCredentials();
                 await SecureStorage.SetAsync(AppConstants.LoggedIn, AppConstants.False).ConfigureAwait(false);
                 await navigation.NavigateAsync(AppConstants.LoginPage).ConfigureAwait(false);
             }
             else
             {
                 await navigation.NavigateAsync(AppConstants.MainPage).ConfigureAwait(false);
             }
         }
         Profile.ProfileImage = null;
         Barrel.ApplicationId = Configurations.ClientID;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Crashes.TrackError(ex);
     }
 });

Everything is working in debug mode but in release mode
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes] ERROR: +[MSACWrapperLogger MSACWrapperLog:tag:level:]/10 Unhandled Exception:
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.InvalidNavigationException: Expected Navigation Failed. No Root Window has been created.
   at Prism.Navigation.PrismWindowManager.CreateWindow(Application app, IActivationState activationState)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Microsoft.Maui.IApplication.CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions.CreatePlatformWindow(IApplication application, UIWindowScene windowScene, NSDictionary[] states)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions.CreatePlatformWindow(IUIApplicationDelegate platformApplication, IApplication application, UIApplication uiApplication, NSDictionary launchOptions)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiUIApplicationDelegate.FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
   at Jacobs.Platforms.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)

how to fix this issue?

This error is thrown if you don't call InitializeComponent in your constructor of your Application (App.xaml.cs)
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

